# How to have an empty col-md-* in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have two unequal columns in Bootstrap.
I want to have one column on each side (so if there are columns from 1 to 12, 1 and 12 will be empty), and col-md-2~5 is one column, and 6~11 is another column.

I can't really find an example for this (other than the offset). Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi there, You need to think how this will look on smaller screens. There is no point in having a space on the left and right on a mobile screen. This is why it is best to use `col-xx-offset-xx` so that you can **ZERO** the offset when needed. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't want to use offset as per your requirement, use

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:red">
     <div class="col-md-1" style="background:yellow">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="col-md-4" style="background:green">B</div>
     <div class="col-md-6" style="background:red">C</div>
     <div class="col-md-1" style="background:yellow">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, I think you should use offsets

Answer (score 59):

Use [offsets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). You only need to define the first offset as the second *col* will float next to the first.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background:#f99" class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">Cols 2-5</div>
    <div style="background:#9f9" class="col-xs-6">Cols 6-11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>**Note:** I'm using the `xs` column size so it works in the snippet frame.</sub>

---

Note, for Bootstrap 4, the offset classes use different names. The `col-*-offset-*` classes become `.offset-*`.

See http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/ for a handy migration guide

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="background:#f99" class="col-4 offset-1">Cols 2-5</div>
        <div style="background:#9f9" class="col-6">Cols 6-11</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

Comment: I came to this as the first Google result but had some trouble. Maybe a change in versions? Official documentation seems to say "offset-xs-1" is the syntax as of v4.2.1, rather than "col-xs-offset-1" as in v3.3.5 above.